# How to modify combo boxes lists in .esriAddIn, with no access to Visual Studio or SDK

Tags: arcgis-10.0, add-in, visual-studio, sdk, combo-box

I have an .esriAddIn project made for ArcGIS 10.0, and I want to modify the combo boxes lists with up-to-date values. My organisation has moved forward with Visual Studio 2013, ArcGIS 10.3, and relevant SDKs. The issue is that the esriAddIn project created by these versions doesn't work in ArcGIS 10.0. ESRI no longer provides older versions (to replicate ArcGIS 10.0 environment). So, here is the question:

How do I modify the combo boxes in the .esriAddIn project so as to be used in ArcGIS 10.0? I have no access to past Visual Studio and relevant SDKs, and the newer ones create esriAddIn that is not accepted by ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, if you edit and recompile using VS 2013 with ArcGIS 10.3 your addin will only work with 10.3 and upwards. Who is using 10.0? Tell them to upgrade. There are many benefits to upgrading; bugs fixed, new tools etc.